# Disable alt+f4 in chromium

Tags: raspbian, node.js, chromium

I currently have a Basic X Server with [matchbox window manager](https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/embedded/matchbox-window-manager) with opens a [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) (was called node-webkit) chromium browser.
matchbox has by default all hotkeys deactivated.
The only thing left ist the internal alt+f4 handling from chromium.

Is there some way to prevent the [nw.js application](https://nwjs.io/) from closing?

Comment: The answer to your question is "don't press ALT+F4", but I assume the real question here is how to prevent the user from closing your app no matter what keys they press.

Answer (score 1):

Remap F4 to something else using

```
 xmodmap -e "keycode 70 = F3"
```

After that, for all progams running under X11 your keyboard will appear to have two F3 keys and no F4 key.